# Adding custom UIView to UIAlertController

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, xib

I have custom xib that contains radiobuttons.
I'm trying to add this xib into alertcontroller as subview.
but the text is going out from the uiview as you can see:

[image]

[image]

```
let alert = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("MyXib", owner: self, options: nil)!.last as! UIView

    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "\n\n\n\n\n\n", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
    let margin:CGFloat = 8.0

    let rect = CGRect(x: margin, y: margin, width: alertController.view.bounds.size.width - margin * 4, height: 300)

    let customViewForAlert = UIView(frame: rect)
    customViewForAlert.addSubview(alert)

    alertController.view.addSubview(customViewForAlert)
    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

How I can fix it ?
thanks

Comment: As mentioned in the answer - you can't. But here's two things you *can* do: (1) Use your xib file as a modal presentation view controller. (2) Use it in a popover - but be aware that on an iPhone you'll have to add some extra code to make it such.

Comment: You can do it upto some extent, but you should not.Please refer this link for more info   https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uialertcontroller

Answer (score 0):

From Apple's docs:

**The UIAlertController class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified.**

Please, create custom view, add content to it, and show it in your view controller.